# Copying Files to directory from Multiline Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, copy, multiline

I am trying to write a C# program that will allow me to select a file and copy that file to a list of directories.

I've written the code to copy the file over and it works, the problem I am having to getting it to copy the file to each line of the textbox, as each line is a different directory.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int line = 1;
    string FileToCopy = listBox3.GetItemText(listBox3.SelectedItem);
    if (File.Exists(FileToCopy + @"\user.ini"))
    {
        File.Copy(FileToCopy + @"\user.ini", textBox1.Lines[line - 1] + @"\user.ini", true);
        line++;
        label5.Text = "Environment Updated";
    }
    else
    {
        label5.Text = "File of Path not Found";
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is a simple solution to this but my searches haven't brought up anything yet. I'm still quite new to C# and programming in general, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: split the text into lines and for each line perform the copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming textbox has text

```
Path1
Path2
Path3
.....
PathN
```

Then split the text into lines

```
var lines = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And then for each line copy the file over.

```
foreach(var path in lines) {
    File.Copy(FileToCopy + @"\user.ini", path + @"\user.ini", true);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an Argument 1 error: cannot convert 'string' to 'char'